# Plotting z as a color with R on a rGoogleMap

Tags: r, heatmap, rgooglemaps

I have a function and I want to plot only `x` and `y`. `z` should be represented as a color. Is there a package that does the work for me ?

```
f = function(a,b){
   dnorm(a^2+b^2)
}


x = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)
y = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)
z = outer(x, y, f)
persp(x, y, z)
```

I want to plot this function on a map generated with `rGoogleMaps`. Maybe there is a more specific package for this use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
library(ggmap)         # loads ggplot2 as well
library(RgoogleMaps)   # for getGeoCode
london.center <- getGeoCode("London")
london <- get_map("London", zoom=12)
x    <- seq(-2,2,0.1)
df   <- expand.grid(x=x,y=x)
df$z <- with(df,f(x,y))
df$x <- london.center[2]+df$x/20
df$y <- london.center[1]+df$y/20

ggp <- ggmap(london)+
  geom_tile(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z), alpha=0.2)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(guide="none",colours=rev(heat.colors(10)))+
  stat_contour(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z, color=..level..), geom="path", size=1)+
  scale_color_gradientn(colours=rev(heat.colors(10)))
plot(ggp)
```

This solution uses `ggplot`. Perhaps someone else will show you how to do this using `RgoogleMaps`.

Basically, we load the map, using `get_map(...)` (which is just a wrapper for `GetMap(...)` in the `RgoogleMaps` package).

Then we create the sample data frame `df`, which contains three columns, `x`, `y`, and `z`, and one row for every combination of x and y (this is the format required by ggplot).

Then we create the map layers. First the map itself, using `ggmap(...)`; then a layer of tiles "filled" based on the value of z, using `geom_tile(...)`; then a set of contour lines colored using the value of z, using `stat_contour(geom="path",...)`. The rest of the code sets the fill and line colors and renders the map.

Purists will tell you that you can render the filled contours directly using `stat_contour(geom="polygon",...)`, instead of using tiles, but this has the unfortunate effect of clipping any contours not completely enclosed in the plot area.

Comment: I just found this post and learning from your answer. Would you please explain what you are doing between `x <- seq() and df$y <- london.center[1]`? Why do you create sequence between -2 and 2? Is this because you want to cover the whole ggplot graphic area? I would like to know what `london.center[2]+df$x/20` means as well.

Comment: @jazzurro - The function `f(x,y)` is defined in OP's question as the radial PDF of the normal distribution. The limits (-2,2) are also from the question. Since OP didn't provide any data, I chose London for an example. Grabbing the data for London at `zoom=12` provides roughly +/- 0.2 degrees in latitude and longitude (as you can see from the map). So I re-scaled x and y from OP's question by dividing by 20, to fit everything on the map. Adding the centroid of London simply translates the x- and y-values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I now see what you were doing in this answer. Cheers.